# What is the best OS,development tool for Magento development?

Tags: windows, macos, magento

I am totally new to Magento and have few question. This question might be off-topic but, I am not even sure for Magento, if it is please point me in the right direction/forum etc.

I am beggining magento development and need to know if magento development is OS dependent?
I can develop on windows 7, Mac OS X mavericks 10.9.5 and Windows 8.1.

I found the page below with lots of utility programs and I am not yet sure which programs work on which platforms. What type of development tools "must" I use (IDEs,FTP file managers,text editors)?
http://www.kingletas.com/2012/08/magento-developer-toolbox.html

I would like to develop it on my mac mini but don't want to have problems later on.

I also read that Magento uses MVC. I learned the pattern in iOS development. Are there other design patterns that I should know right from the start?

I also read that Magento has a backend and frontend. Does this mean that the frontend developer develops and works on the layouts,views (in MVC) while the backend developer works more on the model and with the controllers?

Are there something like "WWDC 2014" videos for Magento?

Thank you :)

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems whatever OS you use. I personally perfer Linux because of case sensitivity, but Mac also is case sensitive and thus would also work. Case sensitivity becomes relevant when using PHP `include` statement and on windows it will work with mixed casing and on linux would not. So when you develop on Windows it may seem to work but on UNIX wouldn't.

Comment: Great. I will then go with OS X for now.